# Map does not appear after following ESRI example of flex api

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, browser, flash-builder

I followed the example from ArcGIS resource center website: https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/ to create a map, unfortunately after I run the flex builder application, the map does not appear. The following is my code and what happens after running the application. What's wrong with my project? I have tried to use IE, Chrome and Firefox to open the url, but the result is the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/2008/ags">

<esri:Map level="3" wrapAround180="true">
    <esri:center>
        <esri:WebMercatorMapPoint lon="0" lat="0"/>
    </esri:center>
    <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
        url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/
        World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
    <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer
        url="http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/
        Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer" 
        alpha=".70"/>
 </esri:Map>

</s:Application>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep the value of `url` for `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` and `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` in a single line. Like
`url="url_value_in_sigle_line"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
    xmlns:esri="http://www.esri.com/2008/ags">

    <esri:Map level="3" wrapAround180="true">
        <esri:center>
            <esri:WebMercatorMapPoint lon="0" lat="0"/>
        </esri:center>
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer
            url="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer
            url="http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Population_World/MapServer"
            alpha=".70"/>
    </esri:Map>
</s:Application>
```

[image]

Comment: @ppLily: If you accepted this answer then please click green tick next to it. This will reduce the number of unanswered questions.